# Fatal error message: uncaught exception 102

Tags: facebook

I have an facebook application. In my app it's able to pull your friends list where you can search by name or stroll down to find friend. When I type in the search box to find friend I keep getting error message Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: 102: Requires user session thrown in /home/chattabo/public_html/fbappdev/src/base_facebook.php on line 123. What does this mean and do anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Did you check the Facebook API developer docs?

Comment: @Madbreaks the facebook dev docs seems to have nothing to say about this.  I am having the same problem, and it appears to have just started recently, as all posts on the subject seem to be within the last month...

Comment: @TrassVasston See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734737/fql-error-102-requires-user-session-on-a-repeated-query/13750967#13750967